# What happens to statements after DoCmd.Close?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-forms

What happens to statements that are written on the lines after a `DoCmd.Close` statement in a private sub in a form? Are they executed prior to the from being closed?

```
Private sub aaaaa ()
  DoCmd.Close
  DoCmd.Openform "frmA"
  Run xxx
End Sub
```

Is `frmA` opened?

Is the sub procedure `xxx` executed?

Comment: Yeas, the form opens and the sub is run. I just want to understand what happens logically with repect to the form - events subsequent to DoCmd.Close.

Answer (score 0):

`DoCmd.Close` - will close the active object which is opened in MS Access and ask for confirmation in case of any unsaved changes.
Look at official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.close) for Parameters to pass to `Close` method.

> You can use the Close method to close either a specified Microsoft Access window or the active window if none is specified.
>
> If you leave the ObjectType and ObjectName arguments blank (the default constant, acDefault, is assumed for ObjectType), Access closes the active window. If you specify the Save argument and leave the ObjectType and ObjectName arguments blank, you must include the ObjectType and ObjectName arguments' commas.

Is frmA opened?

> Yes, it will open the form with name "frmA".

Is the sub procedure xxx executed?

> Yes, it will proceed with the next procedure execution.

Comment: I accept that and testing shows it does work. However, can someone explain the events from the execution of the DoCmd.Close statement to the moment the form actually closes.

Comment: Please check the updated answer, let me know if it helps.

Comment: No, I have read (and probably understood) the official documentation. However, it does not give an answer to my question. Let me try to re-phrase it. If I have a procedure with only one statement, DoCmd.Close, the form closes immediately. If I have more statements AFTER the DoCmd.Close statement has been executed, the form does not close. Does this mean that a form does not close before the End Sub statement has been reached (in the sub containing the DoCmd.Close statement)?